# Is it possible to store a Base64 encoded image into IndexedDB and have each image stored to have a unique ID/name?

Tags: javascript, database, base64, indexeddb

as the titles say. i have no code to show as its done in my company's database and i cant share any information online.

Im completely new to this... any help would do

Comment: Yes it is possible. You are not going to get a great answer without providing more information.

Comment: Consider Base64 as just a string. Since you can keep plain strings in IndexedDB, you can keep Base64 value as well. You could've provided a code snippet that you tried.

Comment: @Josh Sorry, im new to doing b64 and indexedDB, sorry for not providing more information

Comment: @PetroCliff https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/ this was something i tried using but didnt seem to work